# UITextfield in a Grouped UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to implement an input form on an iPhone app by using a grouped static table view.

I'm using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to lazily create a textfield and add to the relevant cell.

[image: Screenshot]

My problem is that `becomeFirstResponder` is not behaving as I would expect.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(!self.contactNameTextField)
    {
        self.contactNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(93, 14, 200, 20)];
        self.contactNameTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.contactNameTextField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
        self.contactNameTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        [self.contactNameCell addSubview:self.contactNameTextField];
    }

    [self.contactNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];

}

if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    if(!self.contactEmailTextField)
    {
        self.contactEmailTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(93, 14, 200, 20)];
        self.contactEmailTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.contactEmailTextField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
        self.contactEmailTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        [self.contactEmailCell addSubview:self.contactNameTextField];
    }

    [self.contactEmailTextField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

The code steps through as expected.

If I tap section 0 first, the name textfield becomes first responder. If I then tap section 1, the email textfield becomes first responder. If I then tap on section 0, even though `becomeFirstResponder` is called on the name textfield, it does not respond.

Also, if I tap section 1 first, even though `becomeFirstResponder` is called on the email textfield, it does not respond.

Please advise

Comment: Try NSLogging self.contactNameTextField at the top of the method and see if it is saving the reference.

Comment: just found it, cut and paste issue with self.contactNameTextField in twice, thank anyway lads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, silly cut and paste error with self.contactNameTextField in twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling resignFirstResponder of other textfield before calling becomeFirstResponder of it.
Replace

```
[self.contactNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

with

```
[self.contactEmailTextField resignFirstResponder];
[self.contactNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Do same for section 1.  Before calling resignFirstResponder check if textField in not nil.